# Faction Membership Limits in Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

Are there any limitations to the faction memberships you can have in Fallout 4?

I'm brand-new to the Fallout universe, and just got to the point of being invited to the Brotherhood of Steel. However, I'm a bit concerned about their politics and how it may affect my standing with other factions I may encounter.

If I join the Brotherhood, will there be other factions that I can't join? Are there any other factions that have such limitations?

Note: I'm still not very far into the game, and not very familiar with the Fallout 4 universe in general, so please make liberal use of spoiler markdown in your answers. Essentially, the only things that need to be un-spoilered are Yes/No answers for the questions asked above.

Answer (score 3):

**If I join the Brotherhood, will there be other factions that I can't join?**

No.

**Are there any other factions that have such limitations?**

No, [but they're not friendly with each other and you will be forced to choose in order to finish the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243589/52800) (contains spoilers).

Comment: Also: **If I join the Brotherhood, will I lose a little favor with companions who are allied with an opposing faction?** Yes. Im not sure how much, or what actions actually "displease" them, but Preston had something to say about me joining the Brotherhood.

Comment: Piper disliked me joining the Brotherhood, but it did not affect the romantic relationship level enough to really change anything.  And she's easy to keep happy by picking locks.

Comment: The dislike penalty for a companion doesn't appear to be sufficient enough to stop you romancing them although I'm still testing what happens if you destroy the institute with the courser as a companion