# Do factions and companions care what other factions you associate with?

Tags: fallout-4

Similarly to Skyrim, I want to join ALL of the factions in Fallout 4.

If I join the Brotherhood of Steel, will the Minutemen care?

Will Preston leave me as a companion if I join the Brotherhood of Steel?

If I join X, will Y care...etc?

Will companion X leave me if I join X faction?

Comment: From another question, factions don't matter until the end of the main story where you can choose which faction side with, and they will want you to kill off the other factions. I don't have any specifics to how it works, just what I've read elsewhere.

Comment: Related: [What are the long-term consequences of joining each faction?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243589/52800)

Comment: Unlike Skyrim, you can't be 'grandmaster' in all the factions at the same time, and finish all their quests.  At some point each faction will have you destroy another faction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as joining goes, you can join all of them without any problem, at least at first. I'm a member of all factions and no companion complained so far.

I even took Nick Valentine with me when visiting the Brotherhood, which results in a few comments but nothing more.

At some point there are consequences for doing certain missions with a faction, but I stopped before the point where I have to decide and avoided it so far. So I can't tell anything more about the late game. But you can certainly join all the factions at first without worrying about your companions.

Comment: There was another post, that if I read correctly, stated there are "points of no return" where completing the next quest will disable quests of the competing faction. But that also could be end-game. I cannot remember exactly.

Comment: @DangerZone That was my own question. And while I haven't played far enough to see the points of no return, I went up until the point where quests directly impacted other factions, which I assume will impact my relationships with those factions once I complete those quests.

Comment: I would assume that as well, that is a fair point.

Comment: I've also heard there's a PNR somewhere around the middle or mid-late stages of the main story. I wouldn't say the companions don't complain, but they (and usually the ambient NPCs) aren't nearly as vocal as I'd expect them to be. Took a BoS guy to a Railroad hideout. Hung around there forever before he finally said something like, "You're the only reason I don't open fire and burn this place to the ground right now".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can join any faction while belonging to any other factions.

There is however a point where you have to select loyalties and then your companions will care.

For example, I went with the Institute, which resulted in destroying the Railroad and the BoS. After than I returned to Red Rocket Truck Stop, where all my companions where and I was attacked by Danse (BoS) and Deacon (Railroad).

The others did not care or react.

Comment: This is basically the same answer than the existing one. These kind of answer are redundant and subject to deletion here.

Comment: Considering the other answer did not at the time and still does not confirm what happens late game and mine does, I wouldn't say its redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Siding with BoS wil result in a quest

"Big near-end game Spoiler Ahead"

> where Danse is revealed to be a synth and he is exiled. You will be
>  tasked with hunting down and killing him. You can choose to let him
> live, but he will still be exiled and he will get into fights with other
>  members of the Brotherhood.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer the question properly only faction specific companions will leave you if you join a faction all others will just complain.

Answer (score -1):

Okay so, you can have every companion until you choose one faction for good there are three companions and you will have one available for each faction if you choose the railroad you can have Deacon but not Paladin Danse Or X6-88, there might be a response from your current companion when you end the game but they will not leave you for that for example, I chose the institute for my first game and Piper was pissy but I didn't get the, "Piper Hated That." or, "Piper disliked that." only Deacon, Danse, and X6-88 will either leave/attack you for choosing one side like Danse tried murdering me after the institute.